# How do I set up a cronjob to run scheduled jobs?

Tags: joomla, cron-job

I have a Joomla 3.3.3 installation with CiviCRM 4.6.10 and Siteground is my host. I have never set up a cronjob before. I have tried to use Sitegrounds Cronjob tool in cPanel which uses Linux commands which I am also unfamiliar with.

The support staff helped me create a command string - /usr/local/php53/bin/php-cli /home/ashguild/public_html/home/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php - but I get the following

ERROR: You need to send a valid user name and password to execute this file

I haven't been able to find out how to include the username/password in the string or even if that's really the problem. As you can tell, I am very inexperienced and would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you should add directly after cron.php

```
?name=username&pass=password&key=site-key
```

so it will be in your case:

```
/usr/local/php53/bin/php-cli /home/ashguild/public_html/home/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=username&pass=password&key=site-key
```

The site-key is generated during install and can be found in civicrm.settings.php.

For your joomla you should be able to find it in
/home/ashguild/public_html/home/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

Comment: Thank you. I used that formatting and ran the cronjob with Terminal. The error message is gone but the following was returned - Results: [1] 31561
[2] 31562 and I don't know what this means and I didn't see any evidence that the Scheduled jobs were run. Should the username/password be for Joomla or for Siteground?

Comment: should be the joomla username and password

Comment: The crobjob still doesn't seem to be running although I am not getting an error message. When I ran it through Terminal, it just returned - [1] 21217
[2] 21218 and there was no evidence that the jobs were run. Any idea what those numbers mean?